# How to generate logs with name like log-{ClassThatInvokesLogger}-{Data}?

Tags: java, log4j

I need to set logfile name like `log-{ClassThatInvokesLogger}-{Data}`. Is it possible to get classname in extended `FileAppender`? This article [How to create a new log file for each time the application runs](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/08/how-to-create-a-new-log-file-for-each-time-the-application-runs/) says how to add timestamp data to the log file name. But how to get `{ClassThatInvokesLogger}` from the `ExtendedFromFileAppender` class?

The feature is used for testing. I need to create a new log for every test.

Comment: Are you sure that's a good idea? If you need to analyze the logs by class, you can easily split it up. If you have a decent amount of classes that do logging, it'll make it nigh impossible to detect errors.

Comment: I have a few testcases that create a new log after every execution. I need to know, which testcase created the log not by opening the log, but just from the logfile name. This feature is additional because we have one more collected log with general info from every testcase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workeround for this issue. MyFileAppender class should have the following

`String fileName = logFile.getName() + System.getProperty("InvokingClassName");`

At the same time the test that invokes logger should have something like this

`@BeforeClass
    public static void loggerInicialization(){
        System.setProperty("InvokingClassName", "MyInvokingClassName");
        logger = Logger.getLogger(MyInvokingClassName.class);
    }`

In this case InvokingClassName will be accessible and can be used in the log file naming. However probably there is a better solution

Answer (score 0):

```
this.getClass().getName()
```

Will retrieve the name of the class of the current object.

Comment: The logic of new file naming is implemented in MyFileAppender class that is extended from FileAppender. So I need somehow to get LoggerInvokingClassName within  MyFileAppender class. this.getClass().getName() gets only "MyFileAppender".